# Microsoft sql triggers auto update GPA when new grade is added to the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

There are 2 tables:

Students(studentid, LName, FName, GPA)

Enroll(enrollid, CourseID, Semester, Grade)

I want to create a trigger that updates GPA every time a new grade is added, the calculations are
`gpa = (old.gpa + new.grade)/count(grade) where studentid = new.studentid`

Here is my code but it won`t work

```
Create trigger [dbo].[stud_marks] 
on 
[dbo].[enroll] 

after INSERT,update 


AS 
DECLARE @id as int
DECLARE @newgrade as int
SELECT @id = studentid, @newgrade = grade
FROM inserted

begin
UPDATE students
set gpa = (gpa + @newgrade)/count(@id)
end
```

it shows an error:

```
Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Procedure stud_marks, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 7]
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
```

Comment: Pleas don't SHOUT at us; we can read lower case letters fine, thank you.

Comment: Storing aggregated values in a table is almost always a bad idea. If you want to make such values available as a column use a `VIEW`.

Comment: Thanks man but is there a way where I can implement this with a trigger?

Comment: If you find yourself using local variables in a trigger you are almost certainly [doing it wrong](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: In your `TRIGGER` what is `@newgrade`? You define it, but never assign it a value, so it'll be `NULL`. This means that `WHERE grade=@newgrade` will return no rows and `@Count` will be assigned the value `0`, so you'll get a divide by zero error.

Comment: If you want to monitor inserts of `GradeValues` why is the trigger defined on `students`? I really don;t understand your schema, can you explain the foreign key relationships? Much better to just use an indexed view

Comment: I edited it, does my question make more sense?

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. You are assuming that inserted will only ever contain a single row. This is not how triggers work in sql server, inserted will contain ALL the rows from the insert statement. But as said before, storing calculated data is problematic. A view would be a much better solution for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this isn't a good idea, isn't 3NF, and invites inconsistent data.  These are Bad Things, and don't do them.

That being said, the problem wasn't with your trigger, it's with your UPDATE.

You're not limiting the update to a soecific student, and you're trying to perform an aggregate in an update, which is a no-no.  This is the way your update should look, which I implemented in an old-fart way and didn't use WITH, but a)I'm an old fart, and b), you've taken me away from watching my "Matlock" marathon to write this.  Anyway, here's the update you *should* have written.

```
UPDATE students
set gpa = (select avg(grade) + @newgrade from enroll where studentid=@id)
    /(select count(*)+1 from enroll where studentid=@id )
where studentid=@id
```

Ok, now I have to go back to doing old-fart things.  And if you any of you whippersnappers give me an "Ok, Boomer", just remember--I can operate a manual transmission.